# How do you pass a paramater in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am confused on how parameters work since I'm quite new at this. I want to pass the variables `HEXformat` and `RGBformat` to `validatecolor`. The `validatecolor` is supposed to validate if the given variable is a valid HEX or RGB colour and is outputted as a boolean.

My question is: How do I pass the `HEXformat` and `RGBformat` as a parameter to the `validateColor` function?

```
function onFormSubmitted(RGBformat, Hexformat){
  var colorvalue = document.getElementById('colorvalue').value;

  var RGB = document.getElementById("RGB").checked;
  var HEX = document.getElementById("HEX").checked;

  if (RGB == true) {
    var RGBformat = "rgba(" + colorvalue + ")";
    alert(RGBformat);
  } else if (HEX == true) {
    var HEXformat = "#" + colorvalue;
    alert(HEXformat);
  }
  return HEXformat, RGBformat;
}

window.validateColor = (color) => {
  let colorRegExp = new RegExp(/^#([\da-f]{3}){1,2}$|^#([\da-f]{4}){1,2}$|(rgb|hsl)a?\((\s*-?\d+%?\s*,){2}(\s*-?\d+%?\s*,?\s*\)?)(,\s*(0?\.\d+)?|1)?\)/igm);

  let matchResult = color.match(colorRegExp);

  let isValid = ((matchResult == null) ? false : true);

  // this function returns a <boolean> value (i.e. returns true when the specified color is valid and false when color is invalid)
  return isValid;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `onFormSubmitted`?

Comment: The `/.../` syntax creates a regular expression instance. You don't need to call new RegExp()

Comment: What is the question? What doesn't work or don't you understand? [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3982562)

Comment: I'm calling the onFormSubmitted via an onsubmit in html form

Comment: My question is how do I pass the HEXformat and RGBformat as a parameter to the validateColor function?

Comment: Do you want to call `validateColor` from the `onFormSubmitted` function? Or do you want to use the return value of `onFormSubmitted` to call `validateColor`? You never show where and how you call `validateColor` in the question.

Comment: Yes, I want to return the value of onFormSubmitted (RGBformat, HEXformat) and pass it to the validateColor

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by the code you're showing. From reading the code it seems like `onFormSubmitted` doesn't use the defined parameters and should only produce a single output:

```
function onFormSubmitted() {
  var colorvalue = document.getElementById('colorvalue').value;

  var isRGB = document.getElementById("RGB").checked;
  var isHEX = document.getElementById("HEX").checked;

  if (isRGB) {
    return "rgba(" + colorvalue + ")";
  } else if (isHEX) {
    return "#" + colorvalue;
  }
}
```

You can then pass the return value like this:

```
const color   = onFormSubmitted();
const isValid = validateColor(color);
```

Note that the return value of `onFormSubmitted` can be `undefined` (if neither RGB or HEX is checked). So you might want to wrap the `validateColor(color)` call with an *if*-statement, to validate the presence of `color`.